# Error: exceeds block gas limit undefined

Tags: go-ethereum

I am using geth 1.9.12. When I try to deploy any contract, using the console, I get the error: **Error: exceeds block gas limit undefined** What exactly is this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is your code???

Comment: I use remix to create the contract. The code I use is the WEB3DEPLOY from Compilation details.

Comment: Please share your contract code AND your deployment code as part of your question, in **plain text** (no links or images).

Comment: pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

contract SampleContract {
    
    
    bytes32 testValue;
    
    function setValue(bytes32 value, uint256 requestCode)
    {
        testValue = value;
        ValidationAndPaymentEvent(requestCode);
    }
    
    function getValue() public view returns(bytes32)
    {
        return testValue;
    }
    
    event ValidationAndPaymentEvent ( // STEP 7
        uint256 requestCode
    );
    
}

Comment: In your question please. And properly formatted. Thank you.

Comment: The contract code is in the above comment. I can not share the deployment code. Generally the deployment code is extracted from remix ( Compilation Details -> WEB3DEPLOY )

Comment: And you consider that code readable inside the comment?

Comment: I created a second question with the contract code (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82521/error-exceeds-block-gas-limit-undefined-2). However I think the problem is with geth.