# Error: exceeds block gas limit undefined (2)

Tags: go-ethereum, remix

I am using geth 1.9.12. When I try to deploy any contract (below the code), using the console, I get the error: **Error: exceeds block gas limit undefined** What exactly is this error?

Thanks in advance.

pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

contract SampleContract {

```
bytes32 testValue;

function setValue(bytes32 value, uint256 requestCode)
{
    testValue = value;
    ValidationAndPaymentEvent(requestCode);
}

function getValue() public view returns(bytes32)
{
    return testValue;
}

event ValidationAndPaymentEvent ( // STEP 7
    uint256 requestCode
);
```

}

Comment: Which network are you trying to deploy in?

Comment: In a Private-network, constructed with geth 1.9.2 . In previous versions of geth, I did not have this problem.